# problem with leaflet in a smarty template

Tags: leaflet, openstreetmap, smarty3

I'm using SmartyBC on version 3.1.33. In the smarty template the code of leaflet and openstreetmap will not run. The map will not open.

I've all tested with or without the script between {literal} {/literal}. The map will not open. However, in a normally html site the code works perfectly. What's the mistake?

```
 <html>
 <head><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.5.1/dist/leaflet.css">
 <script src='https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.5.1/dist/leaflet.js'></script>

#map {
  height: 500px;
}
</head>

<body>
<div id="map"></div>

<script>
{literal}
var map = L.map('map').setView([43.64701, -79.39425], 15);

L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map);

L.marker([51.5, -0.09]).addTo(map)
  .bindPopup('A pretty CSS3 popup.<br> Easily customizable.')
  .openPopup();
{/literal}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

No error messages and no map. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't put #map styles in HTML `<style>`. I did that and the same code without `{literal}` tags worked.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vqVLjL

Comment: Thanks, I already know the code works on a normally html site. The big problem is that the code does not run in a smarty template, as google maps it does between {literal} {/literal}.

Comment: If the code looks right when you are checking it in source view (Ctrl + U) then it's a frontend issue not smarty.

Check if you don't have typo in HTML `<script>` because the second thing I would suspect is that your scripts are executed before library is available on the page (you didn't wrap your code in document ready/load) but this would give you errors in console.

Comment: Thank you Sir for helping! Now I've found the problem. The div element always must be in front of the script ..for whatever reason. The script necessarily must be between {literal} {/literal}.

Comment: The div element must be place before the script because you didn't wrap your functions in onload event, so they are executed before you have access to this DOM element, but this should trigger error `Error: Map container not found.` in your console earlier.